# Hibernate (JPA,JSF 2.0, Spring) switch from HyperSQL to Oracle - Configuration is being ignored

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, c3p0

i'm currently in the process of working on a midsized Webproject, using JSF 2.0 with Spring.As IDE i use Eclipse with JBoss Tools. The Webapp is deployed to a Tomcat v7.0 Server.
I use Hibernate/JPA/C3P0/ to connect to the Database (previously HyperSQL) I now tried to switch to an Oracle DB, which i did a number of times before and it never was a problem, however now it seems, that the changed configuartion is just being ignored. When i fire up the  Server, it still uses the HyperSQl Driver and the old DB, although i cleaned the workdirectory of Tomcat, removed and redeployed the Webapp (which i built from scratch of course). 
The project is split in two, one webapp and one service part. The project are dependent in Eclipse. However, although all of the businesslogic is implemented in the service layer, i can just remove it and the webapp doesn't throw an error and i can start it as if nothing has changed. This tells me that it must be cached somewhere and it is not refreshed on the server...I also deleted the server, added a freshly downloaded instance - still the same thing...Does anyone have an Idea what this could be about?

Here is my service.spring.xml:

```
    <!-- Enable processing of @PersistenceContext and @PersistenceUnit -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Enable transaction configuration with @Transactional -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Configure a c3p0 pooled data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dburl"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the JPA entity manager factory with Hibernate -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mygourmet"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configure transaction manager for JPA -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And my persistence.xml:

```
 <persistence-unit name="mygourmet" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
```

I used the exact same configuration on another project and it works like a charm...Any hints are highly appreciated, thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Tomcat by default unpacks your war file. Have you removed the war and the unpacked folder?

Comment: i use the JBOSS tomcat plugin for eclipse, so eclipse should take care of that automatically, but thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved -  i did a mvn clean install, generated new eclipse projects and imported them back into eclipse. It seems the changes in my service module were not recognized by eclipse.